# Ansible Fetch fails to copy file in use from windows

Tags: windows, ansible

The following step fails on windows if the file is in use:

```
- name: copy MyLog.log
  fetch:
    src: "C:\\MyLog.log"
    dest: "{{ agent_log_dir }}"
    flat: yes
    validate_checksum: no
```

*ERROR*

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\\MyLog.log' because it is 
being used by \r\nanother process.\"\"\r\nAt li
```

What's the best approach to dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `agent_log_dir` variable contains a trailing slash?

[comment from the Ansible modules core repository](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3375#issuecomment-213005022):

> Assuming your dest is a dir, you need a trailing slash on it. Linux fetch will fail explicitly in this case (sans-trailing-slash will tell you it's a dir, with trailing slash will do what you expect). The Windows fetch is failing to error on the sans-trailing-slash case, and just downloading the file to nowhere.

So assuming this is the case here you will need to set a trailing slash in the `dest` parameter.

Comment: Given it works when the application writing to the log isn't running, I don't think that is the problem.